# VBA counter with excel database

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some macros for an excel worksheet that will add points to a database. The entries need to be unique with respect to their latitude and longitude values, so I've added a a few lines of code that will check the lat/long of an entry after a user has tried to enter it. It is intended to check the lat/long of a pending entry against all the ones in the database. If it matches one, it will return an error. Here is the code:

```
x = 2
Do Until (Worksheets("DBase").Cells(x, 3).Value = "")
     If Worksheets("DBase").Cells(x, 3).Value = lat And Worksheets("DBase").Cells(x,
4).Value = lon Then
          GoTo coorAbort
     Else
          x = x + 1
     End If
Loop
```

x is the row counter, lat and lon are the lat/long's inputted by the user, and coorAbort is the section with the error message. Everything works fine except the counter to progress the loop to the next row doesn't seem to be working. It checks the second row entry and then exits the loop and moves on to the next part of the code. I'm sure I have something small messed up, I just can't seem to pick it out. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm testing it with only two database entries. When I try to add a third with the same lat/longs as the first entry, it goes to the coorAbort error message as it should. However, if I try to add a third with the same lat/longs as the second entry, the counter actually does work (from stepping through with the debugger), and it does the comparison in the if statement, but some reason finds that they don't equal each other and continues on through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `lat` and `lon` are double values? If so, you should replace

```
If Worksheets("DBase").Cells(x, 3).Value = lat
```

by

```
If Abs(Worksheets("DBase").Cells(x, 3).Value - lat)<1e-6
```

(and for `lon` do the same). Never test double values directly for equality.

Comment: You're right... well, in a sense. lat and lon were strings, and the problem wasn't in my code, necessarily. The formatting in Excel was rounding the decimals, so even though the same values were being inputted to excel, the rounded version was being compared to the input version.